# Limiting Linked Table Results

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that I have linked from another database that has both Active and Inactive employees.  I am only wanting to see the Active employees inthe linked table.  I know how to do this through a query, but I dont want to have a query if there is a way to only show records that have a "Active" in the Status field.

Comment: So you want to open the linked table in Datasheet View and see only a subset of the total rows --- those where `Status='Active'`.  Is that correct?

Comment: So you only want certain rows yet you do not want to use a query? You could create a view if the other linked database isn't access. In access, saved queries essentially function as views.

Comment: HansUp you are correct. I am not too sure how to limit to the active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your linked table open in Datasheet View, click the `Status` column then apply a filter ... in Access 2007, click the filter (funnel) icon on the "Sort & Filter" section of the "Home" ribbon.  Choose "Equals" from the "Text filters" dropdown of the resulting dialog and enter `Active` in the text area.  Click OK and save the table layout by clicking the save icon or with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

Then open the table in Design View.  Click yes to "open it anyway" when it warns you that you can't modify the design of a linked table.  (You won't be modifying the table *design*, but you will be changing an item in its `TableDef.Properties` collection.)  From there, open the table's property sheet, locate the "Filter On Load" property and set it to `Yes`.  Close the table and click `Yes` when Access asks whether to save the change.

If my instructions were adequate, you should see only those rows with `Status="Active"` when you reopen the linked table in Datasheet View.

Here is a screen capture from my system where I saved a filter expression, `([AssetMovements1].[AssignedTo] Like"a*")`, for my `AssetMovements1` linked table.

[image: Table Property Sheet]

Those properties could be set from VBA code if you prefer.  Just beware that `Filter` is a user-created property which means it doesn't exist in the `Properties` collection until you assign it a value.  From code, you would need to use the `CreateProperty` method and then assign the property value.

Comment: Thank you. If you like, you can add the code I ended up with, to your answer - [vba code](http://pastebin.com/6iSrrtA2)